# use instr on ListAGG

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, listagg

I want to use ListAgg and then use INSTR/REGEXPR on top of it to understand if the resultant string has a combination of strings or not.

Example

```
appNumber   Decision
123         AB
345         BC
123         PA
345         PA
123         AM
```

I want to list them together using LISTAGG and then put INSTR to say if the LIST AGG has both "AB" and "AM"

Result will be

```
Appnumber         MyResult
123               1
345               0
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Hi,  -   this doesn't make a lot of sense. Are you saying, if appNumber 123 has the decision strings BA and MC, and the concatenation is BAMC, then this string DOES have the substring AM? (If that is not what you are saying, and AM must be either a value in Decision or a substring of a value in the Decision column, then you can test independently of LISTAGG). If in fact you want BAMC to result in a match of AM, then ... LISTAGG depends on the order of aggregation, but you didn't mention anything about that. MCBA, which is the other possibility, does not contain the substring AM.

Comment: @mathguy you have a point, with the example I gave. However in real life this will not happen. Sorry to create confusion. Also using LISTAGG, I'd be separating them with a comma. And it is not a substring of the column. It is all of it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother using LISTAGG at all; a simple sum + group by and a couple of case expressions do the job just as well:

```
with sample_data as (select 123 appnumber, 'AB' decision from dual union all
                     select 345 appnumber, 'BC' decision from dual union all
                     select 123 appnumber, 'PA' decision from dual union all
                     select 345 appnumber, 'PA' decision from dual union all
                     select 123 appnumber, 'AM' decision from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table called "sample_data" that contains your data
select   appnumber,
         case when sum(distinct case when decision = 'AB' then 1 
                                     when decision = 'AM' then 2
                                     else 0
                                end) = 3 then 1
              else 0
         end myresult
from     sample_data
group by appnumber;

 APPNUMBER   MYRESULT
---------- ----------
       123          1
       345          0
```

This works by assigning each of the decisions you're searching for a value of a power of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8, etc) and then using the resultant sum of the distinct values to compare against the total of all those values. In your case you're searching for 2 strings, so you're checking for a sum equalling 3 (if you were checking for the presence of 3 strings, it'd be 7 (1 + 2 + 4), 4 strings would be 15 (1 + 2 + 4 + 8), etc).

Whether this is any more performant than Tim's answer using listagg is anyone's guess; I suggest you test both versions and see which one works best for your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you not restricted to use ListAgg I may suggest you the other solution without analytical functions. I used collections to let external application pass your states ('AB', 'AM') in a function like an array of strings. This function returns result set as a nested table.

preliminary type declarations:

```
create or replace type t_test_states is varray(10) of varchar2(2);
create or replace type t_test_appnumbers is table of number;
```

creating a function (in real life you won't have block with a subquery 'ample_data'):

```
create or replace function TEST_GET_ANSWER (p_states IN t_test_states)
    return t_test_appnumbers 
  is
    v_resultset t_test_appnumbers;
  begin      
    with sample_data as (select 123 appnumber, 'AB' decision from dual union all
                         select 345 appnumber, 'BC' decision from dual union all
                         select 123 appnumber, 'PA' decision from dual union all
                         select 345 appnumber, 'PA' decision from dual union all
                         select 123 appnumber, 'AM' decision from dual)

    select appnumber bulk collect into v_resultset
      from (
            select appnumber
              from sample_data
             where decision in (select column_value from table(p_states))
             group 
                by appnumber
                 , decision     
           ) 
     group               
        by appnumber
    --the next condition ensures that appnumber has exactly ALL states
    having count(*) = (select count(column_value) from table(p_states));

    return v_resultset;
end TEST_GET_ANSWER;
```

And using the function looks like this:

```
select * from table(test_get_answer(t_test_states('AB','AM')))
select * from table(test_get_answer(t_test_states('PH')))
select * from table(test_get_answer(t_test_states('PA')))
select * from table(test_get_answer(t_test_states()))
```

Comment: That is a great solution too. Thank you.